# Selecting an autocomplete item is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, razor, autocomplete

I have the following field inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
<input  class="push-up-button searchmargin" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text" style="margin-top:8px"/>
```

and i wrote the following autocomplete function:-

```
$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000,

            create: function () {
                $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $('<li>').append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.resourcename + ' | ' + item.customername +  ' | ' +item.sitename + '<hr>' +'</a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

Currently the auto complete is working well (the result list will be displayed), but the problem is that if i select an item from the auto complete result it will not be rendered inside the auto complete field.and when i check the firebug i noted the following error , when selecting an auto complete item:-

```
TypeError: item is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

self.element.val( item.value );
```

For example if i start typing the following words "i am" , then i select "I am writing" from the autocomplete list result , then the autocomplete field will have the "I am" text instead of the select "I am writing". Can any one advice , what is causing this problem?

Thanks

**EDIT**

i edited my autocomplete as follow, by adding focus & select :-

```
 $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },

            create: function () {
                $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $('<li>').append('<a>' + '<b>'+item.label + '</b><br>' + '<span style="color:#8e8e8e ">' + item.resourcename + ' | ' + item.customername + ' | ' + item.sitename + '<hr style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">' + '</span></a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                };
            }

        });
    });
```

but i wil get the following error when i am trying to select an autocomplete item:-

> TypeError: ui.item is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Please add "Select" event and try below

```
 $( "input[data-autocomplete-source]" ).autocomplete({
       select: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "input[data-autocomplete-source]" ).val( ui.item.yourValueProperties);
         return false;
      }
  });

***Note : yourValueProperties= like customername ***
```

Comment: this will raise the following exception on firebug :TypeError: ui.item is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").val(ui.item.label);

Comment: did you getting ui.item == null ??

Comment: as i mentioned using you r code , i will get TypeError: ui.item is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").val(ui.item.label);

Comment: Okay John, I could see your code for testing because data will coming dynamic (MVC). please check this link may you will get solution  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: please add event  focus: function( event, ui ) {
$( "input[data-autocomplete-source]" ).val( ui.item.label );
return false;
}, and try it

Comment: i can not write ".autocomplete( "instance" )" and i need to write create: as i am using jquery 1.8.2 and jquery-ui version 1.8.24